# SQL - Only accept capital letters by constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersoon
    ADD Geslacht char(1) NULL
    CONSTRAINT CKGeslacht CHECK (Geslacht in ('M', 'V'))
```

When I execute this query, afterwards it is still possible to insert 'm' or 'v' in the column called 'Geslacht' in TblPersoon.
How can I make sure that only capital letters are accepted?

I know I should be able to do this in SQL Server Management Studio, but where?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a case-sensitive collation.  You can define the column that way, or do it in the `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersoon
    ADD Geslacht char(1) NULL
    CONSTRAINT CKGeslacht CHECK (Geslacht collate Latin1_General_CS_AS in ('M', 'V'));
```

or:

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersoon
    ADD Geslacht char(1) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
    CONSTRAINT CKGeslacht CHECK (Geslacht in ('M', 'V'));
```

Collation in general is a bit of a tricky subject.  It involves the relationship between different characters.  In SQL Server it also seems to be conflated with the character set ("code pages").  I do which that basic things like case-sensitive vs. case-insensitive comparisons did not require using them.  You can learn more about it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You can define explicit *collation* like that :

```
ALTER TABLE TblPersoon
ADD Geslacht char(1) NULL
CONSTRAINT CKGeslacht CHECK (Geslacht collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS in ('M', 'V'))
```

However, i have used default *collation* case-sensitive type `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` you can change it accordingly.

Comment: This did the job! Thanks